# Map returning no text for the span next to checkboxes jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dictionary, text

I am using a map function to return the span's text following clicked checkboxes. It returns no output.

```
<label class="hello">
  <input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="1">
  <img src="test1.png">
  <span>test-1</span>
</label>
<label class="hello">
  <input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="2" checked>
  <img src="test2.png">      
  <span>test-2</span>
</label>
<label class="hello">
  <input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="3" checked>
  <img src="test3.png">
  <span>test-3</span>
</label>

checked = [];

$('.hello').change(function() {
     checked = $('.hello input:checked').map(
         function() { return $(this).next('span').text(); }).get();
     alert(checked);
});
```

alert returns ',,'.

Comment: When debugging issues like this, try splitting your code into more lines. Variables are your friend. You can see in the debugger exactly what $(this).next('span') is if you set it equal to a variable and call .text() on that variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's next returns the 'immediately following sibling' if it matches. The element that immediately follows your checkbox is not the span, it's the img tag. The .siblings() function should work.